# Relation between periodic and continuous functions?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is there any relation between them? I know that every periodic and continuous function is bounded and uniformly continuous. For counterexamples of periodic $\implies$ continuous or continuous $\implies$ periodic: the second one is pretty obvious. For the first one, define $f:\mathbb{R}^{+}\to\mathbb{R}$:
$f(x)=x-\lfloor x \rfloor$, then $f$ has period $1$ but is obviously not continuous. Is this a good example?

Comment: Yes, it is a perfect example.